# Alamofire completion handler not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I'm currently trying to call a `prepareForSegue` method in an AlamoFire completion handler but it's not being called.  Here is my code:

```
func loginMember (username: String, password: String, completionHandler: (String?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {

  let headers = [
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  ]

  let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [

    "grant_type" : "password",
    "username" : username,
    "password" : password,

  ]

      Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseURL)/oauth2/token", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
          switch response.result {
          case .Success:

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
              completionHandler(nil, response.result.error)
              return
            }

            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)

              accessToken = swiftyJsonVar["access_token"].stringValue

            print("This is the login response:\(swiftyJsonVar)")

          case .Failure(let error):
           print("Sorry there was an error: \(error)")

            return
          }

      }

    }
```

This is what it looks like when called:

```
loginMember(username, password: password, completionHandler: { error in

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToHomeSegue", sender: self)
  }
  }
)
```

Any ideas as to why the `performSegueWithIdentifier` isn't being called?

Comment: You're only calling it in the case when the guard statement fails

Comment: I didn't realize that, how can I change it so it's called when its succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only calling your completion handler in the case where you enter your guard statement.  You need to add calls for the case where you get your access token and your error case.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseURL)/oauth2/token", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:

                    guard let value = response.result.value else {
                        completionHandler(nil, response.result.error)
                        return
                    }

                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)

                    accessToken = swiftyJsonVar["access_token"].stringValue

                    print("This is the login response:\(swiftyJsonVar)")

                    // Got the token, call handler
                    completonHandler(accessToken, nil)

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Sorry there was an error: \(error)")

                    // Got an error, call handler
                    completionHandler(nil, error)

                    return
                }
        }
```